# NSIS has 2 ways of declaring variables and for Conditional Statements

Tags: syntax, nsis

Something thats really annoying me with NSIS is why there are 2 different ways of doing things?

1. Why have 2 ways of performing conditional statements/logic. Ie, use '$if' or use 'StrCmp'?
2. Why be able to store variables in many different ways. Ie, use '$myvar' or use 'var myVar' and I think theres more
3. Why have assembly to access store variables? Why not just use the above methods
4. Why can you create a comment by using both ';' or '#'

Can you suggest a link that documents all the global variables? Such as $INSTDIR and others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clearly haven't understood all of how NSIS works.

1. `${If}` and all of those things are from LogicLib, which was added to the NSIS standard library after it had been in existence for a long time. Formerly, you had to use `StrCmp`, `IntCmp`, or one of those jump operators. `${If} a == b` is just syntax sugar around `StrCmp` with the labels all taken care of. It produces much more maintainable code.
2. `Var foo` is the variable *declaration*. `$foo` is *accessing* the variable. They are thus quite different things. You can't use `$foo` without having already specified `Var foo`.
3. I haven't a clue what you mean by this.
4. Does it matter?
5. Look in the manual. It's all there in plain sight. Try the [Variables](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.2) section.

Answer (score 0):

The list of reserved variables is available in the documentation. Writable variables are in section 4.2.2, and constants are in 4.2.3.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.2.2